# WCF Data Push & DataServiceCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

Using the DataServiceCollection class, is it possible to expose an EDM through OData wcf feed that automatically pushes data to a client? Using some form of automatic change-tracking?

Basically I have multiple Odata feeds exposing sql records through Entity Framework, and want them all to push to a single client location on either scheduled intervals or when a certain amount of new data is present. They should only push NEW records in the database at each time, therefore each service would have to recognize which records are new as compared with the last push.

The data could alternatively be pulled from the single client, but there has to be some seamless recognition of what data is new, and what is old, basically.

Is this the intended use or capability of DataServiceCollection, or is there some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData is great for many things but synchronization is not one of them.  If you can assume that SQL Server will also be used on the other end, take a look at SQL Replication.

Comment: You are right. The problem is that I dont really have that option right now, I believe more than just SQL Express is required for replication? Additionally, its not just straight synchronization of the data. I only need to consolidate certain specific objects (transformations of the relational data using EF, sometimes very complex transformations) on the client end. I also want it to be easy to track new EF views of the data without having to change too much hard code.